# Populating multi-dimensional array using getValues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to populate a multi-dimensional array with the values of 3 contiguous cells using getValues, but when I do this, I seem to be getting an extra set of brackets that prevents me from  using the array as intended later in the code.

```
var finalsArray = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];

var x = 0;

for(var i = 4; i <= finalsLastRow; i++) {

 finalsArray[x] = finalsSheet.getRange(i, 7, 1, 3).getValues();

 x++;

}
```

Using this method, finalsArray[x] returns [[88.0, 95.0, 43412HOUOKC]].

But I want finalsArray[x] to return [88.0, 95.0, 43412HOUOKC].

I am able to achieve this and get rid of the extraneous bracket if I populate the array individually using getValue separately for each cell (see below), but I would love to optimize my code and understand why getValues is not working.

```
var finalsArray = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];

var x = 0;

for(var i = 4; i <= finalsLastRow; i++) {

 finalsArray[x][0] = finalsSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
 finalsArray[x][1] = finalsSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
 finalsArray[x][2] = finalsSheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();

 x++;

}
```

Thank you very much for any help you guys can provide.

Ryan

Comment: `getValues` returns a "2D" array, in which the outer elements are rows and the inner elements are values of that row. So for an N-row getvalues call, you get `[ [r1c1, r1c2, ..., r1cN], [r2c1, r2c2, ...], ..., [rNc1, ...] ]`. To me it looks like you could just do `finalsArray = finalsSheet.getRange(numHeaders + 1, 7, finalsSheet.getLastRow() - numHeaders, 3).getValues()` where you have set the `numHeaders` appropriately (e.g. 3)

Comment: got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference the first element of the returned value in place

```
for(var i = 4; i <= finalsLastRow; i++) {
 finalsArray[x] = finalsSheet.getRange(i, 7, 1, 3).getValues()[0];
 x++;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, that did the trick! However, as someone who just switched over to appscripts from VBA a few weeks back, I am not quite sure I understand WHY that does trick. Can you shed any light on that?

Comment: The returned value from finalsSheet.getRange(...).getValues() is a double array. However the outer array has just one element: the inner array. So all the [0] is doing is referencing that one element, inner array.

Comment: Not that this only works properly as intended due to the '1' in the getRange (which is the max amount of rows the method will return parameter)

Comment: @PetervanderWal I think you mean "Note that..." :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel  / PetervanderWal  Thank you both - that makes perfect sense and helps a lot. Really appreciate it!